# Typolinks target not working after upgrade to typo3 8.7.20

Tags: upgrade, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

after upgrading from **Typo3** **7.6.30** to **8.7.20** my **typolinks** are not working correctly. The resulting links in the website have **_blank** as target.
No matter if the links are internal links or external links.

Comment: I found out, if I add `ATagParams = target=_self`, it seems to work

Comment: I know that I could change my menu script and don't uses the automatic creation of the links by using doNotLink = 1 and creating TEXT objects and make my on links. But there has to be some reason why the behaviour changed with the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something lets TYPO3 think you always have external URLs.
what is your domain definition, `absRefPrefix`, `baseURL`?
have you a clean `https`-handling?

Comment: problem occurs only with typolinks not with links that come from e.g. rte. and before upgrading it worked.

Comment: everything is a typolink on some level - except you build a-tags yourself. even then the URL could be a typolink (`returnLast = url`). what kind of url do you link? page uids, records uids, 'internal' url with path, ...? which parameters, anchors?

Comment: it's mostly links to pages, so page uids.

Comment: and it also happens in my HMENU / TMENU

Comment: I assume there is something strange in your domain definition. any mismatch between target domain and current domain (e.g. https which gets redirected to http by a proxy, so all links must be generated with https, but the server is called with http from proxy). What are your domain record definitions? do you use `absRefPrefix = /` ? baseUrl?

Comment: both are the same 

`config.baseURL=https://example.net/
config.absRefPrefix=https://example.net/`

Comment: At first I only used absRefPrefix without baseURL but even if I use both and they are identically, it does not work.

domain record is exmaple.net (no http or https) and no slashes

Comment: using both can not work, baseURl is prefixed to every url by the browser, absRefprefix is prefixed by TYPO3. in general the best solution is ommiting baseURL and using `absRefPrefix = /`. bonus: you can transfer the configuration to any website, (e.g. dev, test, live) without changing any domains.

Comment: ok, so until now we used config.absRefPrefix=https://example.net without baseURL I will give absRefPrefix=/ a try

Comment: Do you have a suggestion, where I can debug this? maybe the class name where the url for HMENU and TMENU is created in typo3. Or wherever typo3 makes the decission if it has to create an internal or an external link?

Comment: maybe you can find some hints [in the API](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_frontend_1_1_content_object_1_1_content_object_renderer.html#a9dba8797c72bca9b021a928119185f10)